# Restrictions.sqlRestriction Parameter index out of range

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I would like to Search for “whole word match” in MySQL and Hibernate.

My code is:

```
public Collection<Template> findByOneTag(String tags) {
    // since the tags are in , format we will replace it with |
    return getSession().createCriteria(Template.class)
            .add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("tags REGEXP '[[:<:]]?[[:>:]]'", tags.replaceAll(",", "|"), StandardBasicTypes.STRING)).list();
}
```

and Template:

```
    @Entity
public class Template implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="template_id")
    private int templateId;

    @Lob()
    private String content;

    @Column(name="method_id")
    private byte methodId;

    private String subject;

    private String tags;

    @Column(name="template_name")
    private String templateName;

    private String thumbnail;
}
```

However I get:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkBounds(PreparedStatement.java:3729)
```

as well as the ? is not being replaced with tags.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following restriction:

```
"tags REGEXP ?"
```

and passing the following value as parameter:

```
"[[:<:]]" + yourOriginalParameter + "[[:>:]]"
```